# French equivalents of the adage-like concept: "You can't please everyone at the same time"

Tags: expressions

While I was answering someone's question on Russian SE, I found myself looking for a close rendering of the adage-like German expression:

> Wer es allen recht machen will, läuft Gefahr, es am Ende keinem recht zu machen.

- *Those who try to please everyone may well end up pleasing no one.*

Or you can say:

> Wer es allen recht machen will, tut sich selbst damit keinen Gefallen.

- *You are doing yourself no favours by trying to please everyone.*

Here I'm not looking for a literal translation of the sentence, but rather an adage-like expression that conveys the idea of
"*You can't reasonably expect to please everyone at the same time {dismissively said}*".

Answer (score 4):

Peut-être [moins courant](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas%20plaire%20%C3%A0%20tout%20le%2Cpas%20faire%20plaisir%20%C3%A0%20tout&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpas%20plaire%20%C3%A0%20tout%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpas%20faire%20plaisir%20%C3%A0%20tout%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpas%20plaire%20%C3%A0%20tout%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpas%20faire%20plaisir%20%C3%A0%20tout%3B%2Cc0) (?), mais je vais dire :

> On ne peut pas faire plaisir à tout le monde.

Ce serait dans le sens de [*satisfy*/contenter](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/please/602566) (Larousse en ligne).

En ce qui a trait à la deuxième formulation on pourrait dire *tu (ne) t'aides pas en essayant de faire plaisir à tout le monde*.

---

D'autre part j'ai jeté un coup d’œil du côté de chez La Fontaine pour trouver d'autres sources d'inspiration :

> [...]
>  Parbieu, dit le Meunier, est bien fou du cerveau
>  Qui
>   prétend contenter tout le monde et son père.
>    [[*Le meunier, son fils et l'âne*](http://www.la-fontaine-ch-thierry.net/meunfils.htm)]

et, différemment :

> [...]
>  C'est un dessein très dangereux
>  Que d'entreprendre de
>   te plaire :
>  Les délicats sont malheureux ;
>  Rien ne saurait
>   les satisfaire.
>   [[*Contre ceux qui ont le goût difficile*]](http://www.la-fontaine-ch-thierry.net/contrgou.htm)

Comment: + 1 On apprend encore et toujours les Fables de La Fontaine en primaire en France et la phrase de La Fontaine sous une forme ou sous une autre (*on ne peut pas faire plaisir à tout le monde/on ne peut pas plaire à tout le monde et à son père*) est encore très présente en France avec la référence spécifique à La Fontaine quand c'est sous forme écrite (presse, livre, etc.). Une rapide recherche sur le net m'a montré que c'est aussi populaire au Québec.

Answer (score 2):

The closest is a well known French proverb:

> On ne peut pas plaire à tout le monde.

It can be found for example here:

> « Eh bien ! lui dit-il en lui montrant un de ses nouveaux ouvrages, cela n’a donc pas le bonheur de vous plaire ? — Non, répondit Villiers. — Cependant, reprit le roi, il y a bien des gens qui n’en sont pas si mécontents. — Cela peut être, repartit Villiers, chacun à son avis. » Le roi, en riant, répondit : « On ne peut pas plaire à tout le monde. »

Voltaire, *Le siècle de Louis XIV*, 1751

---

Note: While "to please" seems closer to *faire plaisir* (to make someone happy) than to *plaire* (to be liked, to be popular), I prefer the second form (*plaire à*) which is much more used and has an overlapping meaning with "to please" anyway.

TLFi
**[PLAIRE](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plaire)**, verbe
**A.** − *Empl. trans. indir.*
**1.** [Constr. avec un suj. nom.]
**a)** **Qqn plaît (à qqn)**. Éveiller la sympathie chez quelqu'un, être une source d'agrément, de satisfaction pour quelqu'un.
[...]

Comment: That was rather unexpected. So basically, what appears to be the most straightforward phrasing -- without the additional "*à la fois*", "*décemment*" etc -- turns out to be the one most commonly used, huh?

Comment: Incidentally, how do you personally say "*You are doing yourself no favours by trying to please everyone*" colloquially?

Comment: Non colloquially: *En essayant de plaire à tout le monde, tu ne te rends pas service.*, colloquially *En te la jouant gentil(le) avec tout le monde, tu te grilles*.

Comment: Never heard of the pronominal "se griller" used like this. What is its meaning (both literal and figurative)?

Comment: *Se griller* means to lose credibility in front of people as a consequence of doing a mistake. It is probably a little too strong compared to "doing yourself no favours" but that's the first colloquial expression that came to my mind. http://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/14058